# Confusing moment in proof of Doob Dynkin lemma in Probability with Martingales by D Williams.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am having really tough time in understanding the proof of [Doob-Dynkin's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma) as given by D Williams as follows
[image: pg1]
[image: pg2]

I can follow upto the point where a sequence of $<X_n>$ of elements of $\mathcal{H}$ is assumed such that $0 \leq X_n \rightarrow X \leq K$. By hypothesis $\forall n \exists f_n \in b\Sigma, X_n = f_n o Y$. It is clear that $\forall x \in Y(\Omega), f_n(x) \leq K$. From this we have $\limsup f_n(x) \leq K$ for $x \in Y(\Omega)$. However I fail to understand how does this lead to $\limsup f_n \in b\Sigma$.

On wikipedia, an additional condition of $Y(\Omega) \in \Sigma$ is mentioned. Did the author miss this condition in his proof above.

Comment: Are you worried that $\limsup f_n$ may not be a bounded function?

Comment: @d.k.o. exactly

Comment: @d.k.o. Will this approach work. Let $S :=  \{x|\limsup f_n(x) \leq K\}$. Then $Y(\Omega) \subset S$. Put $f = 1_{S} \cdot \limsup f_n$. We have $X=f o Y$

Comment: @somita I think, yes. Alternatively, each $f_n$ can be chosen to satisfy $f_n\le K$ so that the $\limsup$ is automatically bounded.

Comment: Yeah, that will do as well.